# submit button click not save courses data when i remove course by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

**Problem**

when i use remove button to remove course.

it will remove from interface(in client side by jquery) but not save course

removed in database(sql server server side) if i click submit button .

when click submit button to save courses in edit view[HTTP POST] it save

success if i adding new courses

**Meaning i can save new course but if i remove course i cannot save**

**image show**

[course removed not save in sql server database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pH21.jpg)

**code**

model class i using is

**updated**

```
public class EditEmployeeVm
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Courses { get; set; }
        public int[] CourseIds { set; get; }
        public List<CourseVm> ExistingCourses { set; get; }
    }
    public class CourseVm
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

**updated**
    edit view[HTTP GET]
     public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {

```
            var vm = new EditEmployeeVm { Id = id };
            var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
            vm.Name = emp.Name;
            vm.ExistingCourses = db.EmployeeCourses
                                    .Where(g => g.EmployeeId == id)
                                    .Select(f => new CourseVm
                                    {
                                        Id = f.Id,
                                        Name = f.Course.CourseName
                                    }).ToList();

            vm.CourseIds = vm.ExistingCourses.Select(g => g.Id).ToArray();
            vm.Courses = db.Courses.Select(f => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = f.Id.ToString(),
                Text = f.CourseName
            }).ToList();

            return View(vm);
        }
```

in edit view get it show code for remove course by jquery

```
@model WebCourse.Models.EditEmployeeVm



    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest(".course-item").remove();
            });
            $('#AvailableCourses').change(function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                var text = $("#AvailableCourses option:selected").text();
                var existingCourses = $("input[name='CourseIds']")
                    .map(function () { return this.value; }).get();

                if (existingCourses.indexOf(val) === -1) {
                    // Not exist. Add new
                    var newItem = $("<div/>").addClass("course-item")
              .append(text + ' <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="' + val + '">Remove </a>');
                    newItem.append('<input type="text" name="CourseIds" value="' + val + '" />');

                    $("#items").append(newItem);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {

            @Html.HiddenFor(g => g.Id)
            @Html.DropDownList("AvailableCourses", Model.Courses, "Select")
            <div id="items"></div>
            foreach (var c in Model.ExistingCourses)
            {
                <div class="course-item">
                    @c.Name <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="@c.Id">Remove </a>
                    <input type="text" name="CourseIds" value="@c.Id" />
                </div>
            }

        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
in edit view httppost that update data in employeecourse table
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditEmployeeVm model)

        {
            var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);

            foreach (var couseid in model.CourseIds)
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Add(new EmployeeCourse { CourseId = couseid, EmployeeId = emp.Id });
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            return View();
        }
```

**update**

i need really to replace my code jquery by usine slice function java script to remove index actually

**update**

i do as below in code

```
 var existingCourseIds = db.EmployeeCourses.Where(g => g.EmployeeId == model.Id && g.CourseId!=null)
                             .Select(f => f.CourseId.Value).ToList();
            var removedCourseIds = existingCourseIds.Except(model.CourseIds);
            //Now loop through these and delete it from db
            foreach (var removedCourseId in removedCourseIds)
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(db.EmployeeCourses.Find(removedCourseId));
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

it give me null exception in the line found inside foreach

error exception value can not null \r\n parameter name entity

link of problem details found in comments below

Answer (score 0):

The `CourseIds` property in your view model will have the ids of the courses user selected (after removing or adding). Now in your HttpPost action method, you need to compare it with the existing data (EmployeeCourses for that employee) and find what course id value does not present in the CourseIds property. That will be the Id user must have removed in the UI. Once you have the Id, you can remove it from the db.

You can use the LINQ Except method to find out the difference between the 2 lists.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(EditEmployeeVm model)
{
    var existingCourseIds = db.EmployeeCourses.Where(g => g.EmployeeId == model.Id)
                              .Select(f=>f.CategoryId).ToList();
    var removedCourseIds = existingCourseIds.Except(model.CourseIds);
    //Now loop through these and delete it from db
    foreach (var removedCourseId in removedCourseIds)
    {
       // TO DO : remove from db
    }
    // Your other save part goes here
    return RedirectToAction("Add");
}
```

Comment: i have two problem in existingCourseIds and removedCourseIds both not have definition

Comment: **both not have definition** What does that mean ????? How hard it is to write a proper meaningful & understandable sentence ?

Comment: first variable existingCourseIds it give error  list<int> does not contain defintion for except and best extension method oveload querable.except.second variable removedCourseIds it give error foreach cannot operate on variable of type ? because not have public definition of getenumerator

Comment: `Except` is an extension method in `System.Linq` namespace. Make sure you have a using statement to import that in your file.

Comment: I know you write meaningful understandable sentence but can you help me more in that in like below i have error http://www.mediafire.com/view/a1uuim3uoi75a9f/wrong4.jpg

Comment: Except method should use the same type of collection at both ends. From your screenshot, your `existingCourseIds` variable is a list of nullable int (` int?`) and `model.CourseIds` is an int collection. That is the reason you are seeing that error message. The right solution to the problem is to change the `CourseId` property in EmployeeCourse table to non nullable int type. If you do not prefer to do that. You can fix your code by doing this. `.Where(g=>g.EmployeeId==modelId && g.CourseId!=null).Select(x=>x.CourseId.Value).ToList();`

Comment: OK it working but inside foreach what i write to delete

Comment: You need to write code for removing the relevant records from EmployeeCourse table for those courses you got in `removedCourseIds` collection.

Comment: i write this  db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(removedCourseId); it give me error cannot convert from int to webcourse.models.employeecourse

Comment: I do not think the Remove method has an overload which takes in int id. you need to pass an object of that class. There are plenty of samples in internet. Just do a google search

Comment: can you tell me how to do remove

Comment: If you do a google search you will get a lot of samples (many from SO itself) or even the official documentation from Microsoft! Try to implement that and if you run into a specific problem while trying to do so, Ask a question with minimal relevant code. No one will here will write code for you if you ask a broad question like the one you asked in prev comment. Also please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i try also by using (var employeecourse eec in removedcourseids) but not accept

Comment: link for error is http://www.mediafire.com/view/c917na1coif8485/wrong5.jpg